# Sass BEM Mixin Sub Components

Tags: css, sass

I am using Sass 3.3 ".scss syntax" to achieve BEM nesting using the following mixin:

```
@mixin e($name) {
  @at-root #{&}__#{$name} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

I am using the mixin like so:

```
.header {
  background:red;

  @include e(logo) {
    background:green;

    @include e(inner) {
      background:blue;
    }
  }
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
.header {
  background:red;
}

  .header__logo {
    background:green;
  }

    .header__logo__inner {
      background:blue;
    }
```

My desired output is:

```
.header {
  background:red;
}

  .header__logo {
    background:green;
  }

    .header__logo-inner {
      background:blue;
    }
```

Notice how the `__` is replaced by a `-` on the `inner` element.

I know I can do this by adding another mixin but I'd like `e` mixin to handle it automatically. My pseudo code for the `e` mixin is something like:

```
@mixin e($name) {
  @if 'sub-component' {

    @at-root #{&}__#{$name} {
      @content;
    }

  } @else if 'sub-sub-component' {

    @at-root #{&}-#{$name} {
      @content;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Hugo Giraudel](https://twitter.com/HugoGiraudel/status/429393799459401728) for the idea my mixin is now:

```
@mixin e($name, $sub-element: false) {
  @if $sub-element == false {

    @at-root #{&}__#{$name} {
      @content;
    }

  } @else if $sub-element == true {

    @at-root #{&}-#{$name} {
      @content;
    }

  }
}
```

The usage is like so:

```
.header {
  background:red;

  @include e(logo) {
    background:green;

    @include e(inner, true) {
      background:blue;
    }
  }
}
```